# ui-router root url redirects to a state with empty url

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a parent state which url is mapped for '/' and when I access the root, for example: http://localhost:8081/sin/TPW/, it redirects me to a child state which has an empty url.

I don't know why it chooses this child state, because there are other child states with empty url too, and they are not called.

The state which is called is **parent.foto3**

```
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

        $stateProvider
            .state('parent', {
                url: '/',
                views: {
                    '$default': {
                        component: 'parent'
                    }
                }
            })

            .state('parent.token', {
                url:'open?k',
                views: buildViews('tokenless', false, true),
            })

            .state('parent.confirmacao', {
                url: '',
                params: {aviso: {dynamic: true}},
                views: buildViews('confirmacao', true),
            })

            .state('parent.cancelada', {
                url: '',
                views: buildViews('cancelada'),
            })

            .state('parent.foto1', {
                url: '',
                views: buildViews('foto1', true),
            })

            .state('parent.foto2', {
                url: '',
                views: buildViews('foto2', true),
            })

            .state('parent.foto3', {
                url: '',
                views: buildViews('foto3', true),
            })

            .state('parent.foto4', {
                url: '',
                views: buildViews('foto4', true),
            })

            .state('parent.foto5', {
                url: '',
                views: buildViews('foto5', true),
            })

            .state('parent.foto6', {
                url: '',
                views: buildViews('foto6', true),
            })

            .state('parent.concluido', {
                url: '',
                views: buildViews('concluido'),
            })

            .state('parent.erro', {
            url: 'err',
                params: {erro: {dynamic: true}},
                views: buildViews('erro'),
            });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('err');
```

Angular: 1.6
ui-router: 1.0.3

Comment: Maybe because its the first match?

Comment: Post all of the other states.

Comment: @scipper No. I ommited the other ones, but it is in the middle.

Comment: @TsvetanGanev done. Take a look, please.

Comment: I can't see any reason, why especially parent.foto3 is called. Won't it actually be better practice, to define url's to each state like `url: "/foto3"` to ensure a more stateful behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I have Noise following things

- if new state name start with "parent"  so it will auto matically set parent state parent
- every state must have unique state name and url template also

[image]

Comment: I set unique url for all the states, and know when I try to access any state through the url I got 404. Example: http://localhost:8081/sin/TPW/foto3